# My client sees grossly defective image, not what I uploaded

Tags: image

Obligatory research done without result. My client (in another state) sees this very pixelated image. The only way I can replicate his view is by zooming in with ctrl + repeatedly. In a brief moment, before the zoom is complete, I see the defective image. Then it becomes clear again. I asked him to use another computer. So far, no response from him. I must resolve this issue. I'll appreciate any help.  The first link shows what I see (and hopefully what you see).

The second link shows what he sees. Client sent it to me as a screen capture.

http://63pounders.com/faculty-biographies.php#core

http://codestruggle.com/bad-image.html

Answer (score 1):

That's a Moiré pattern formed due to subsampling a dotted (halftone) image without blurring first. Especially low-power viewers are likely to implement scaling that way, because blurring is slow. It seems that your viewer also scales that way as a first approximation, in order to react quickly, but then it makes the properly scaled version as well.

You should be able to fix it by scaling the image yourself. You can use responsive images to retain the ability to scale up and to support high DPI.

Comment: As a self-taught (and elderly) developer, I have not yet blocked off time to master images. I do see that as very important. I'm slowly easing my way into media-queries and responsive versions of pages with regard to a range of devices. I have yet to learn responsive images. I just change display sizes with the mq's 'till I can do better. And for that reason, I'm clueless as to what you mean. I do sense that you see client's
display hardware and something less than cutting edge. I'll stand by for a more dumbed down recommendation. But I will study yours until I understand what it all means.

Comment: @perhaps2old2learn the simple option is just to scale the image to some size, so small that the dotted pattern is not visible anymore (or smaller), for example here is a version at 25%: http://i.imgur.com/WdYYXPT.jpg  "cheap scaling" on that will still not be ideal, but it shouldn't be disastrous anymore.

Comment: I know how to downsize images with irfanview or any number of editors. But apparently you're doing something different when you "scale" the image. Would you be so kind as to explain?

Comment: @perhaps2old2learn I used a gaussian filter of a higher strength than required for a 25% scale to get rid of the dots but keep it larger, I would have had to scale much smaller to get rid of the dots otherwise and even then the editor I used (Paint.net) would have used a box filter instead of a proper gaussian filter so it wouldn't have been as good.